How is という used in this sentence?

柔らかい物言いを心がけたつもりだが、少年は叱られたように身構えた。
こういう少年を扱う時はなるべく自然体でいたほうがいい。
……自分という、経験則だ。

What exactly is the composition of the sentence at the end? "A rule of thumb called myself?" I can't quite make sense of way the author used という in this very context.

This Xという is simply "called X". It's the author's unique way of saying "This is based on my personal experience". The word 経験則 is typically used in contexts where someone shares widely-known wisdom with you, but in this case, the author is labeling their personal experience as a "rule", creating a humorous contrast.
If the literal translation doesn't sound natural, something like these might work:

……自分という、経験則だ。
A rule of thumb, or rather, "my two cents".
A piece of wisdom, also known as "my two cents".
This is a life lesson brought to you by me.

The humor comes from using the somewhat grandiose term 経験則 to refer to mere personal experiences. As long as this contrast is preserved, we don't have to stick to the literal translation.

How come you seem to translate 自分 as "my two cents" instead of something like "me" or "myself", even if it isn't literal? This jump in meaning also confuses me in the original, where 自分 is "put into the same category" as 経験則 (i.e. after 自分という I'd expect words like 存在 or  人間).

@Kaskade When a tyrant says "I am the law", this actually means "What I say is the law", right? This is in the same vein. The sentence is saying "What I feel is the 経験則" or "経験則, which actually is my impression".
